# Moving repeating pattern in a div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` container which has a repeating background image that forms a pattern, and I would like to animate it with jQuery so that the pattern moves south-west.

How can this be done?

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/main.css">

    <script src="content/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#container").animate({
            'background-position': '1110px 1110px'
        }, 1000, function () {
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Sprightly](http://spritely.net/). It's a jQuery plugin and makes animating background images reasonably easy.

To pan (animate a background image), the documentation gives this code as an example:

```
$('#trees').pan({fps: 30, speed: 2, dir: 'left'});
```

---

If you're looking for a simpler, lighter approach, [this plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/) may be a better solution. To animate a background, give it an offset:

```
$('.elem').animate({backgroundPosition: '500px 150px'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
    $("#container").animate({
        'background-position': '1110px 1110px'
    }, 1000, function () {
 });
```

...

```
/**
* @author Alexander Farkas
* v. 1.22
*/

(function ($) {
    if (!document.defaultView || !document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) { // IE6-IE8
        var oldCurCSS = $.curCSS;
        $.curCSS = function (elem, name, force) {
            if (name === 'background-position') {
                name = 'backgroundPosition';
            }
            if (name !== 'backgroundPosition' || !elem.currentStyle || elem.currentStyle[name]) {
                return oldCurCSS.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            var style = elem.style;
            if (!force && style && style[name]) {
                return style[name];
            }
            return oldCurCSS(elem, 'backgroundPositionX', force) + ' ' + oldCurCSS(elem, 'backgroundPositionY', force);
        };
    }

    var oldAnim = $.fn.animate;
    $.fn.animate = function (prop) {
        if ('background-position' in prop) {
            prop.backgroundPosition = prop['background-position'];
            delete prop['background-position'];
        }
        if ('backgroundPosition' in prop) {
            prop.backgroundPosition = '(' + prop.backgroundPosition;
        }
        return oldAnim.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    function toArray(strg) {
        strg = strg.replace(/left|top/g, '0px');
        strg = strg.replace(/right|bottom/g, '100%');
        strg = strg.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g, "$1px$2");
        var res = strg.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/);
        return [parseFloat(res[1], 10), res[2], parseFloat(res[3], 10), res[4]];
    }

    $.fx.step.backgroundPosition = function (fx) {
        if (!fx.bgPosReady) {
            var start = $.curCSS(fx.elem, 'backgroundPosition');
            if (!start) {//FF2 no inline-style fallback
                start = '0px 0px';
            }

            start = toArray(start);
            fx.start = [start[0], start[2]];
            var end = toArray(fx.end);
            fx.end = [end[0], end[2]];

            fx.unit = [end[1], end[3]];
            fx.bgPosReady = true;
        }
        //return;
        var nowPosX = [];
        nowPosX[0] = ((fx.end[0] - fx.start[0]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[0] + fx.unit[0];
        nowPosX[1] = ((fx.end[1] - fx.start[1]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[1] + fx.unit[1];
        fx.elem.style.backgroundPosition = nowPosX[0] + ' ' + nowPosX[1];
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, is there anything wrong with this?: http://jsfiddle.net/UXWzY/

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done wrong, it still won't work locally. I added my page to the question.

Comment: This won't work at all because jQuery does not support background image animations natively (much like it doesn't support colour animations), hence the need for a plugin as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Markum LOL I forgot to include the additional script that is needed for this to work. This is why it was working for me but not for you. See my edited post for the script. Save it as a .JS and include it in your page.